# Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseOperations

Tags: django, mongodb, django-mongodb-engine

I am making an application using mongodb and django.i cant find any other way to connect my database with django.So use mongokit for connection
And i getting this error :-

command prompt-

```
 python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/somya/Desktop/backup/admin_python/admin_app/models.py", line 24, in <module>
    from django_mongokit import connection
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongokit/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from shortcut import get_database, get_version, connection
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_mongokit/shortcut.py", line 13, in <module>
    connection = connections['mongodb'].connection
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 129, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django_mongokit.mongodb' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    u'base', u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name BaseDatabaseOperations
```

setting.py-

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'pom',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
    },
    'mongodb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongokit.mongodb',
        'NAME': 'pom',
    },

}
```

pip list:-

```
pip list
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
amqp (1.4.9)
anyjson (0.3.3)
Babel (2.3.4)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
beautifulsoup4 (4.5.1)
billiard (3.3.0.23)
bs4 (0.0.1)
celery (3.1.23)
certifi (2016.2.28)
Django (1.8)
django-bootstrap3 (9.0.0)
django-celery (3.1.17)
django-cors-headers (1.1.0)
django-crispy-forms (1.6.0)
django-datatable (0.2.0)
django-datatables-view (1.13.0)
django-flash (1.8)
django-mongokit (0.2.6)
django-picklefield (0.3.2)
djangorestframework (3.3.2)
flower (0.9.1)
futures (3.0.5)
kombu (3.0.35)
mongoengine (0.13.0)
mongokit (0.9.1.1)
MySQL-python (1.2.5)
numpy (1.11.1)
olefile (0.44)
pandas (0.18.1)
pip (6.0.8)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pymongo (2.8)
python-dateutil (2.5.3)
python-memcached (1.57)
pytz (2016.1)
razorpay (0.2.0)
requests (2.9.1)
setuptools (12.0.5)
six (1.10.0)
tornado (4.2)
validate-email (1.3)
wheel (0.29.0)
xmltodict (0.10.2)
```

Comment: Please include your database settings in your question that will help to debug further...

Answer (score 0):

[django-mongokit 0.2.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mongokit/0.2.6) was released in 2013, so it doesn't support Django 1.8.

It looks like your import error [has been fixed](https://github.com/peterbe/django-mongokit/commit/c830a5fc9a1ecad5b24dbe4f066ae81d4b0b64df), but there hasn't been a release since.

You could try installing the master branch. However, you should think carefully about whether you want to base your project on a library that has not had a release since 2013.

```
# Install master branch
pip install git+git://github.com/peterbe/django-mongokit.git@master

# Or specify commit to install
pip install git+git://github.com/peterbe/django-mongokit.git@b7c10d41675055490a88f7a67f65728465545142
```

Comment: It is showing - requirement already satisfied   ----- Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymongo>=2.5 in /var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mongokit->django-mongokit==0.2.6)

Comment: When it says `requirement already satisfied` for other libraries, that is just for information, it's not an error. If the install command didn't install the master branch, you could try uninstalling it first with `pip uninstall django-mongokit` and then re-installing.

Comment: File "/var/www/html/admin_python/orahienv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/django_mongokit/base.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.db.backends import (
ImportError: cannot import name BaseDatabaseOperations

Comment: In that case you haven't managed to install the master branch, you are still running 0.2.6 which will not work with Django 1.8+